# How to divide two columns in one table and update the third column in sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

My table has six columns. I want `division` of two columns i.e. `Sum1` and `Sum2` in the last column i.e. `Division`. My database is `SQLite`.

```
`Master       Class    SubClass    Sum1    Sum2    Division
 Stationary   Pencil     HB        1000    500     (1000 / 500)
 Stationary   Pencil     H1        500     400     (500 / 400)
 Boxes        Hard Box   Black      20      10      (20/10)
 BOxes        Card Boxes White      40      20      (40 / 20)
```

How to get this division and update `Division` Column?

Comment: What have you tried? Have have you attempted an SQL query? See this documentation: http://sqlite.org/lang_update.html

Comment: I tried `update [table] set [Division] = (sum1 / sum2)`. But updates all the records to `(1000/500)`. I also tried to `Cast`, but doesn't work.

Comment: After the update, is the ``Division`` column updated to literally ``(1000/500)``? Try with a simple select, i.e. ``SELECT Sum1, Sum2, Sum1/Sum2 FROM [table];`` and examine the output.

Comment: Your UPDATE query should work. Show the problem on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5).

Comment: I tried `select (sum1 / sum2) from [table]`. It gives me `1` for all rows. Then I tried to select `(sum2 / sum1)` and the result is `0`. One more thing the query updates all the records to the same value.

Comment: I solved it by `CASTING the first value to FLOAT`. But `DECIMAL` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cast fields to FLOAT, that worked for me.

```
UPDATE [Table] SET [Division] =( CAST([Sum1] AS FLOAT) / [Sum2]);
```